# Parse automatic login for android

Tags: android, user-interface, authentication, parse-platform, development-environment

I am developing an android app and totally a novice in this. For the backend I am using Parse.

I have sucessfully implemented a login screen and it works good.

Now the point is I am trying to detect the current login of the user from cache and doing an automatic login so that user will not be requested to login everytime he opens the app.

I have used this code to get the current user from the cache and opening the welcome class

```
ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
if (currentUser != null) {
// Send logged in users to Welcome.class
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Welcome.class);
        startActivity(intent);
finish();
} else {
// Send user to LoginSignupActivity.class
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
LoginSignupActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
}
```

This works good. But when i try to convert the current user to string so that i can welcome the user, it throws null pointer exception.

```
String strUser = currentUser.getUsername().toString();
```

When I use the above line it throws null pointer exception.

I think am missing something. Pl anyone could guide?

Comment: `ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername()` should return a String .. no need to do `toString()`

Comment: Can you post the code where the nullpointer happens?